# What permissions are required to run VS with IIS

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015

When working on a project that uses IIS (not IIS Express) for local development, what permissions are actually required under window 8? I don't want to run as admin all the time...the first error message I get when running using the Local User Account (LUA) was about Metabase (probably a misnomer, as changing the permissions on that gave the same error message until the config files in inetsrv/config were also available).  Now it builds, but then gives an error message "Unable to start debugging on web server. IIS does not list a web site that matches the launched URL".

The blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2005/02/04/myth-creating-web-applications-with-visual-studio-requires-admin-privileges/ while old, at least hints that it should be possible to manually give myself (or a group that I create) the right permissions.  Just need to figure out what those permissions are...

Comment: Forget about such old posts. When Microsoft requires admin permissions in all its official documentation, it means such a blog post is not reliable at all.

Answer (score 2):

To run VS against IIS you need to run VS elevated (the process needs admin permissions).

From a non-admin account you could run VS "As Administrator", you will also need to do this with the tools necessary to configure IIS.

However I've never tried that, rather I run with a non-elevated admin account so any file changes from within an elevated VS are fully accessible to non-elevated processes.

Additional: note, VS really only needs the Debug Any Process privilege, but giving that one privilege gives the ability to gain all others (with some effort) going through the work to limit the VS process to just that one difference seems pointless.